# How to assert text changes of a element with WebDriver using page objects?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver, pageobjects

somehow I am stucked with this topic. I have a page object class like:

```
By job = By.xpath("//input[@id='job0']");

public Page triggerJob() {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(job)).click();
    return this;
}
```

When the button is clicked, a text is shown instead like "success". Now I want to assert that this text is shown within a test method not within the page object:

```
public void testTriggerJob() {

    driver.get(url);

    Page = new Page(driver);

    Page.triggerJob();

}
```

How do I do that? I tried several approaches but none worked. It would be great if someone could give me a hint - thanks a lot!

Best regards,

Daniel

Comment: What text is that? Can you provide the `html` of the text?

Comment: <td>

    <span id="de.xyz.jobs.Job_0">

        successfully triggered

    </span>

</td>

Answer (score 1):

You can try out one thing -- 
in your PO create a local var and once you perform click find the text. And then in your test method call a method that would return you that text to assert. So it could be like somewhat...

```
private String strSuccessMsg = "";
By spnMessage = By.id("de.xyz.jobs.Job_0");
public Page jobTriggered() {
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(job)).click();
    try{
        strSuccessMsg = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(spnMessage)).getText();
    }catch(TimeOutException toe){
        strSuccessMsg = "Message not found.";
    }
    return this;
}
```

And add another method to return the string stored.

```
public String getMessage() {
    return strSuccessMsg.trim();
}
```

And then in your test method you can perform:

```
driver.get(url);
Page = new Page(driver);
Page.triggerJob();
Assert.assertEquals(Page.getMessage(), "successfully triggered", Page.getMessage());
```

Comment: Nice answer. Exactly what I was going to suggest

Comment: Thanks @Saifur but its a rare guess that might be OP have already applied this approach. The point that i left was what approaches he has worked with... lolz...

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. I tried something similar but without the timeout. The problem is that it's just not finding it:                           org.junit.ComparisonFailure: Message not found. 
Expected :successfully triggered
Actual   :Message not found.

Comment: @daniel.lozynski can u check whether that span or td is under a frame / iframe or modal window?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it, thanks a lot! The issues was that the element looked nearly the same, but after clicking on the button it changed from "//input" to "//span" which I didn't saw. Since I thought it's the same element I used spnMessage in both cases. After realizing that it didn't found the element because the request was done before it appeared. Now I use Thread.sleep(1000) and it works. I was wondering why it's actually not waiting, but hey ;-)

```
public Page triggerJob() throws InterruptedException {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(job)).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    try{
        successMessage = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(jobSuccessMessage)).getText();

    }catch(TimeoutException timeOutException){
        successMessage = "Message not found.";
    }
    return this;
}
```